# get request using python requests module

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to get the flt information and prices through https://www.easyjet.com by using requests module.
Through browser when I filled the form easyjet.com and click on submit, it is internally fetching the data using following call:

https://www.easyjet.com/ejavailability/api/v15/availability/query?AdditionalSeats=0&AdultSeats=1&ArrivalIata=%23PARIS&ChildSeats=0&DepartureIata=%23LONDON&IncludeAdminFees=true&IncludeFlexiFares=false&IncludeLowestFareSeats=true&IncludePrices=true&Infants=0&IsTransfer=false&LanguageCode=EN&MaxDepartureDate=2018-02-23&MinDepartureDate=2018-02-23

when I'm trying to mimic the same by using following code, I'm not getting the response. I'm pretty new to this domain. Can anyone help to understand what is going wrong?
here is my code

```
import requests


url = 'https://www.easyjet.com/en/'
url1 = 'https://www.easyjet.com/ejavailability/api/v15/availability/query?AdditionalSeats=0&AdultSeats=1&ArrivalIata=%23PARIS&ChildSeats=0&DepartureIata=%23LONDON&IncludeAdminFees=true&IncludeFlexiFares=false&IncludeLowestFareSeats=true&IncludePrices=true&Infants=0&IsTransfer=false&LanguageCode=EN&MaxDepartureDate=2018-02-23&MinDepartureDate=2018-02-21'
http = requests.Session()

response = http.get(url, verify=False)
response1 = http.get(url1, verify=False)

print(response1.text)
```

Comment: What are you expecting as the output after you get the response? What do you want to scrape?

Comment: like below {
  "AvailableFlights": [
    {
      "CarrierCode": "EZY",
      "FlightNumber": 2431,
      "SegmentId": "20180223LTNCDG2431",
      "DepartureIata": "LTN",
      "ArrivalIata": "CDG",
      "LocalDepartureTime": "2018-02-23T07:05:00",
      "LocalArrivalTime": "2018-02-23T09:30:00",
      "FlightFares": [
        {
          "SeatsAvailable": 9,
          "Prices": {
            "Adult": {
              "Price": 85.86,
              "PriceWithDebitCard": 100.86,
              "PriceWithCreditCard": 100.86
            }
          },

Comment: In a browser without clearing the session, when I enter above URL I'm getting the response in json format, but while using requests in python I'm not getting any response.